# Randomly select functions

Tags: python, function, variables, random

I am writing a test script which contains different functions for different tests. I would like to be able to randomly select a test to run. I have already achieved this with the following function...

```
test_options = ("AOI", "RMODE")

def random_test(test_options, control_obj):
  ran_test_opt = choice(test_options)

  if ran_test_opt.upper() == "AOI":
     logging.debug("Random AOI Test selected")
     random_aoi()
  elif ran_test_opt.upper() == "RMODE":
    logging.debug("Random Read Mode Test selected")
    random_read_mode(control_obj)
```

However, I want to be to add further test functions without having to modify the random test select function. All I would like to do is add in the test function to the script. Additionally I would also like a way to selecting which test will be included in the random selection. This is what the variable test_options does. How would I go about changing my random generate function to achieve this?

EDIT: I got around the fact that all the tests might need different arguments by including them all in a test class. All the arguments will be passed into the init and the test functions will refer to them using "self." when they need a specific variable...

```
class Test(object):
  """A class that contains and keeps track of the tests and the different modes"""

  def __init__(self, parser, control_obj):
    self.parser = parser
    self.control_obj = control_obj

  def random_test(self):
    test_options = []
    for name in self.parser.options('Test_Selection'):
        if self.parser.getboolean('Test_Selection', name):
            test_options.append(name.lower())

    ran_test_opt = choice(test_options)
    ran_test_func = getattr(self, ran_test_opt)
    ran_test_func()

  #### TESTS ####
  def random_aoi(self):
    logging.info("Random AOI Test")
    self.control_obj.random_readout_size()

  def random_read_mode(self):
    logging.info("Random Readout Mode Test")
    self.control_obj.random_read_mode()
```

Comment: If each possible test function takes different types of arguments, and needs to print a different logging message, there's not really a great way to do this.

Comment: "I would like to be able to randomly select a test to run" -- why?  Why not just run all your tests?

Comment: @mgilson There are several reasons. Firstly there are several thousand different test to run. Each time the script is run it will not cover the all the options so a random assortment should be run. Secondly, the very fact that any order of test could occur is a test in itself. Sometimes the order can cause failures. I plan to have an option to just run through the whole lot as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of functions in python which you can call:

```
test_options = (random_aoi, random_read_mode)

def random_test(test_options, control_obj):
    ran_test_opt = choice(test_options)
    ran_test_opt(control_obj) # call the randomly selected function
```

You have to make each function take the same arguments this way, so you can call them all the same way.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to have some human readable names for the functions, you can store them in a dictionary, together with the function. I expect that you pass the `control_obj` to every function.

EDIT: This seems to be *identical* to the answer by @Ikke, but uses the dictionary instead of a list of functions.

```
>>> test_options = {'AOI': random_aoi, 'RMODE': random_read_mode}

>>> def random_test(test_options, control_obj):
...    ran_test_opt = test_options[choice(test_options.keys())]
...    ran_test_opt(control_obj)
```

Or you could pick out a test from `test_options.values()`. The 'extra' call to `list()` is because in python 3.x, `dict.values()` returns an iterator.

```
>>> ran_test_opt = choice(list(test_options.values()))
```

Comment: what is `d`?  Why not just randomly select one of the values?  `choice(list(test_options.values()))`

Comment: @mgilson sorry fixed that, was leftover from me testing and I had named `test_options` as `d`, forgot to fix. I'll add your example as well. Is there a reason you're calling `list(test_options.values())` instead of just `test_options.values()`?

Comment: python3.x compatability.  IIRC, `choice` requires a list (or at least an indexible object).  Since `dict` objects have no order, in python3.x, you can't index `dict.values()`, so it is no longer a valid input for choice.  Since you don't have *that* many choices, the extra call to `list` should be negligible performance-wise and it'll make your code forward compatible.

Comment: @mgilson thanks, I was kind of expecting it to be about python 3.x. I'll fix that in as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and suggest that you actually use a real unittest framework for this.  Python provides one -- conveniently name `unittest`.  To randomly run a test, it would work like this:

```
import unittest

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        ...
    def test_something_else(self):
        ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = list(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Tests))
    import random
    # repeat as many times as you would like...
    test = random.choice(tests)
    print(test)
    test()
```

To run all the tests, instead you would use:  `unittest.main()` -- I suppose you could toggle which happens via a simple commandline switch.

This has the huge advantage that you don't need to keep an up-to-date list of tests separate from the tests themselves.  If you want to add a new test, just add one and `unittest` will find it (as long as the method name starts with `test`).  It will also tell you information about which test runs and which one fails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrapped your test selecting function and the tests themselves in a class, you could do the following:

```
from random import choice

class Test(object):
    """ Randomly selects a test from the methods with 'random' in the name """

    def random_aoi(self):
        print 'aoi'

    def random_read_mode(self):
        print 'read_mode'

    def random_text(self):
        print 'test'

    # add as many tests as needed here

    # important that this function doesn't have 'random' in the name(in my code anyway)
    def run_test(self): # you can add control_obj to the args 
        methods = [m for m in dir(self) if callable(getattr(self, m)) and 'random' in m]
        test = choice(methods)
        getattr(self, test)() # you would add control_obj between these parens also


app = Test()
app.run_test()
```

This makes it easy to add tests without the need to change any other code.
Here is info on [**getattr**](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other options, look at `functools.partial`. It allows to create closures for functions:

```
from functools import partial

def test_function_a(x,y):
   return x+y

def other_function(b, c=5, d=4):
   return (b*c)**d

def my_test_functions(some_input):
   funclist = (partial(test_function_a, x=some_input, y=4),
               partial(other_function, b=some_input, d=9))
   return funclist

random.choice(funclist)()
```

This lets you normalize the argument list for each test function.